# wxDataViewListCtrl is slow with 100k items from another thread

Tags: wxwidgets

The requirements:

1. 100k lines
2. One of the columns is not text - its custom painted with wxDC*.
3. The items addition is coming from another thread using wxThreadEvent.

- Up until now I used wxDataViewListCtrl, but it takes too long to `AppendItem` 100 thousand time.
- wxListCtrl (in virtual mode) does not have the ability to use wxDC* - please correct me if I am wrong.

The only thing I can think of is using wxDataViewCtrl + wxDataViewModel. But I can't understand how to add items.

I looked at the samples (https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/WX_3_0_BRANCH/samples/dataview), too complex for me.
I cant understand them.

I looked at the wiki (https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxDataViewCtrl), also too complex for me.

Can somebody please provide a very simple example of a wxDataViewCtrl + wxDataViewModel with one string column and one wxDC* column.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

Per @HajoKirchhoff's request in the comments, I am posting some code:

```cpp
// This is called from Rust 100k times.
extern "C" void Add_line_to_data_view_list_control(unsigned int index,
                                                   const char* date,
                                                   const char* sha1) {
    wxThreadEvent evt(wxEVT_THREAD, 44);
    evt.SetPayload(ViewListLine{index, std::string(date), std::string(sha1)});
    wxQueueEvent(g_this, evt.Clone());
}

void TreeWidget::Add_line_to_data_view_list_control(wxThreadEvent& event) {
    ViewListLine view_list_line = event.GetPayload<ViewListLine>();

    wxVector<wxVariant> item;

    item.push_back(wxVariant(static_cast<int>(view_list_line.index)));
    item.push_back(wxVariant(view_list_line.date));
    item.push_back(wxVariant(view_list_line.sha1));

    AppendItem(item);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to call AppendItem from another thread for 100 thousand times? Why not have a shared object, send the wxThreadEvent once and access the shared object from the main thread, i.e. have the loop  that AppendItems in the main thread? Please post code.

Comment: @HajoKirchhoff `have the loop that AppendItems in the main thread?` - I've tried it, it does not helps, it is still slow.

Comment: AppendItem is generally slow. For 100k entries you probably need some kind of "virtual" list control anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one who replied!

@Vz.'s words "If you have any concrete questions, you should ask them" got me thinking and I took another look at the samples of wxWidgets. The full code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/refaelsh/giter/-/commit/c51882d958443d8dbd64953176df243b17df3462). Look at the following classes:

1. TreeDataViewModel
2. TreeWidget
3. TreeCustomRenderer

Answer (score 1):

Appending 100k items to a control will always be slow. That's because it requires moving 100k items from your storage to the controls storage. A much better way for this amount of data is to have a "virtual" list control or wxGrid. In both cases the data is not actually transferred to the control. Instead when painting occurs, a callback function will transfer only the data required to paint. So for a 100k list you will only have "activity" for the 20-30 lines that are visible.

With `wxListCtrl` see https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_list_ctrl.html, specify the `wxLC_VIRTUAL` flag, call SetItemCount and then provide/override

- OnGetItemText
- OnGetItemImage
- OnGetItemColumnImage

Downside: You can only draw items contained in a wxImageList, since the OnGetItemImage return indizes into the list. So you cannot draw arbitrary items using a wxDC. Since the human eye will be overwhelmed with 100k different images anyway, this is usually acceptable. You may have to provide 20/30 different images beforehand, but you'll have a fast, flexible list.

That said, it *is* possible to override the OnPaint function and use that wxDC to draw anything in the list. But that'll get difficult pretty soon.

So an alternative would be to use `wxGrid`, create a `wxGridTableBase` derived class that acts as a bridge between the grid and your actual 100k data and create `wxGridCellRenderer` derived classes to render the actual data onscreen. The `wxGridCellRenderer` class will get a `wxDC`.  This will give you more flexibility but is also much more complex than using a virtual wxListCtrl.

Comment: Its a good idea @Hajo Kirchhoff to use wxListCtrl in "virtual" mode. I've considered it. But it does not have wxDC* columns - this is very important to me. The idea of using wxImageList does no work in my case, I really must have a wxDC* column. Because, this column supposed to represent a drawing of a DAG graph (like in git log), the amount of prepared images in wxImageList is very big.

Answer (score 1):

The full example of doing what you want will inevitably be relatively complex. But if you decompose in simple parts, it's really not that difficult: you do need to define a custom model, but if your list is flat, this basically just means returning the value of the item at the N-th position, as you can trivially implement all model methods related to the tree structure. An example of such a model, although with multiple columns can be found in the sample, so you just need to simplify it to a one (or two) column version.

Next, you are going to need a custom renderer too, but this is not difficult neither and, again, there is an example of this in the sample too.

If you have any concrete questions, you should ask them, but it's going to be difficult to do much better than what the sample shows and it does already show exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you @VZ. for your answer. These words of yours "If you have any concrete questions, you should ask them" got me thinking and I took another look at the samples of wxWidgets. And I got it working. I will post a full summary shortly.